# python 2 on linux EOFError when reading a line with raw_input()

Tags: python

I use python2.4.3 on linux
When i use raw_input() in an independent file,say test.py,it works well.
But when I run the test.py within another source ,say GUI.py with the code:os.system('python test.py &'),the annoying error blows up,this bothers a lot.
Any idea?

Comment: *What* annoying error? And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the programs that causes the error (`test.py`?) to show us. Please take some time to read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well.

Comment: Depending on how the script runs exactly, the Python process might be spawned without an interactive stdin, so when the stdin is empty, you would get the EOFError since `raw_input` has nothing to read from it.

Comment: I think you are right.The test.py may shut down in the GUI.py before I can enter anything.But I thought it would wait,just like when I run ‘python test.py’，it waits for me to enter.

Comment: You should use the `subprocess` module to get more control over the process you are spawning.

Comment: fix it with subprocess,thank you so much.